# df showing 28G of total space, du showing size of '/' as 400+ G

Tags: ubuntu, disk-space-utilization, df, du

I constantly get the `unable to write to *` error, even though I cleaned up a bunch of space.

`df` thinks my disk is 28G in size and 100% full after I deleted a lot of unused files:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        28G   28G     0 100% /
```

The total size of / is now:

```
$ sudo du -hs /
484G    /
```

And here's my physical system info:

```
$ mount
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)

$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA ST1000DM003-1CH1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  30.0GB  30.0GB  primary   ext4            boot
 2      30.0GB  100GB   70.0GB  primary   ext4
 3      100GB   999GB   899GB   extended
 5      100GB   999GB   899GB   logical   ext4
 4      999GB   1000GB  1285MB  primary   linux-swap(v1)
```

---

Update:

The issue was a runaway log file that filled up /dev/sda1. I suppose that what caused `df` to not show stats for anything other than `/dev/sda1` is the fact that they weren't mounted (as output of `mount` shows above. As to why that happened I have no idea, but after freeing some space and restart, the system was able to mount everything properly.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You do realise that du works across filesystem mounts don't you?  so du / counts partition 1,2 & 5 assuming they are all mounted.

Comment: Did you mean to include the `-x` options in your du command perhaps?

Comment: Look over on the right under Related - you'll find the answer to your questions there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having a hard time visualizing this, and aren't quite sure what's in your directory tree, try downloading and using the [ncdu utility](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu/scr) using `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

can't add comments yet, but as @Matt wrote - the issue is with limited space on / which acts as both / and /boot in single fs.
The correct way is probably to separate into 2 filesystems, and mount /boot on /, but that ship has sailed (it would be easier to just reinstall the system, for @Goro ).
without showing us mount and /etc/fstab, hard to tell the mount hierarchy. possibly autofs is involved too...
if you want to see which dirs hold the most space, do

```
sudo du -sh /* | sort -h
```

and ignore /proc /dev /sys as they are all virtual namespaces (they don't take any actual disk space)

repeat the above du for the largest dir to track down the space hoggers etc.